# How can I suppress rotation of 3D graphics?

Tags: graphics3d

Given a 3D image built of a combination several `Graphics3D` objects, is it possible to suppress rotation of the displayed image by the mouse?

To be specific, here is my custom thermometer gauge:

```
thermo[x_, label_String, labelSize_] := Show[{
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
  FaceForm[{White, Blue, Opacity[0.05]}], 
  Cuboid[{-0.25, 0.2, -0.6}, {0.25, 0.23, 0.55}]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0.05, -1.5, 0.}, Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> {120, 300}],
Graphics3D[{Text[Style["-0.3", 12], {-0.15, 0, -0.3}], 
  Text[Style["0", 12], {-0.15, 0, 0}],
  Text[Style["3/16", 12], {0.16, 0, 3/16}] , 
  Text[Style["1/4", 12], {0.16, 0, 0.25}] , 
  Text[Style["0.3", 12], {-0.13, 0, 0.3}], 
  Text[Style[label, labelSize, Bold], {0, 0, 0.45}]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, -1.5, 0}, Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> {120, 300}],
Graphics3D[{LightBlue, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.5], 
  Sphere[{0, 0, -0.4}, 0.11]}],
Graphics3D[{Red, Specularity[White, 20], 
  Sphere[{0, 0, -0.4}, 0.1]}],
Graphics3D[{LightBlue, Opacity[0.5], 
  Tube[{{0, 0, -0.4}, {0, 0, 0.35}}, 0.05]}],
Graphics3D[{Red, Specularity[White, 20], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.45}, {0, 0, x}}, 0.04]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.015], 
  Line[{{-0.07, 0, #}, {-0.09, 0, #}}] & /@ 
   Table[i, {i, -0.3, 0.3, 0.1}]}],
Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[0.015], 
  Arrow[{{0.09, 0, 3/16}, {0.03, 0, 3/16}}], 
  Arrow[{{0.09, 0, 0.25}, {0.03, 0, 0.25}}]}]
}];
```

Try it:

```
thermo[x, "α", 20]
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Its drawback is that it can be occasionally rotated by mistake. This is not desired, of course. How cam I suppress it?

Comment: I thank very much all participants. I like all answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be tricky to position the `Deploy`. I found by putting it outside the `Show` works best:

```
thermo[x_, label_String, labelSize_] := 
  Deploy@Show[{Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
       FaceForm[{White, Blue, Opacity[0.05]}], 
       Cuboid[{-0.25, 0.2, -0.6}, {0.25, 0.23, 0.55}]}, 
      ViewPoint -> {0.05, -1.5, 0.}, Boxed -> False, 
      ImageSize -> {120, 300}], 
     Graphics3D[{Text[Style["-0.3", 12], {-0.15, 0, -0.3}], 
       Text[Style["0", 12], {-0.15, 0, 0}], 
       Text[Style["3/16", 12], {0.16, 0, 3/16}], 
       Text[Style["1/4", 12], {0.16, 0, 0.25}], 
       Text[Style["0.3", 12], {-0.13, 0, 0.3}], 
       Text[Style[label, labelSize, Bold], {0, 0, 0.45}]}, 
      ViewPoint -> {0, -1.5, 0}, Boxed -> False, 
      ImageSize -> {120, 300}], 
     Graphics3D[{LightBlue, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.5], 
       Sphere[{0, 0, -0.4}, 0.11]}], 
     Graphics3D[{Red, Specularity[White, 20], 
       Sphere[{0, 0, -0.4}, 0.1]}], 
     Graphics3D[{LightBlue, Opacity[0.5], 
       Tube[{{0, 0, -0.4}, {0, 0, 0.35}}, 0.05]}], 
     Graphics3D[{Red, Specularity[White, 20], 
       Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.45}, {0, 0, x}}, 0.04]}], 
     Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.015], 
       Line[{{-0.07, 0, #}, {-0.09, 0, #}}] & /@ 
        Table[i, {i, -0.3, 0.3, 0.1}]}], 
     Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[0.015], 
       Arrow[{{0.09, 0, 3/16}, {0.03, 0, 3/16}}], 
       Arrow[{{0.09, 0, 0.25}, {0.03, 0, 0.25}}]}]}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can't rotate it.

Answer (score 15):

A not fully documented way:

```
Show[Graphics3D[..], Method -> {"RotationControl" -> None}]
```

The option can be added directly to `Graphics3D`, `Plot3D`, etc.

---

Edit: There is a (popup) context menu for modifying the view of `Graphics3D` objects.  It's the one you right-click or control-click on the graphics.  This menu can change the view point of the graphics.  The only methods presented here (so far) that prevent this are `Deploy`, `Overlay`, Rojo's `EventHandler` one, and of course `Rasterize`.  A different context menu pops up in those cases.

---

Edit 2: I found a way to take care of the context menu:

```
Style[
  Graphics3D[Cuboid[], Method -> {"RotationControl" -> None}],
  ContextMenu -> FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "Output"], 
  ComponentwiseContextMenu ->
    {"Graphics3DBox" -> FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "Output"]}]
```

You know, `Deploy` is easier, but some may find it interesting.

Comment: I'm not voting for this until you tell me how you found it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't recall.  I'm afraid I might have guessed.  I found `Method -> {"RotationControl" -> ..}}` by looking at "Show Expressions" of graphics functions output.  I was trying to figure out why `ParametricPlot3D` rotates differently than `Plot3D` when manipulated with the mouse.  `None` was probably a guess, or someone told me a long time ago.

Comment: Niiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiice

Comment: @Mr.Wizard There's also `{"Globe", "ArcBall", "TrackBall"}`, as can be seen in the example in Graphics3D's help

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't work in version 7 but by agreement you get +1. :-) ("Show Expression" counts.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and Michael — This is actually documented in `Graphics3D` and has been used before on this site (including once by Michael!) :)

Comment: @rm-rf I don't think the `None` specification is mentioned. But that documentation is so long, I may be wrong.  Search didn't turn it up.

Comment: @MichaelE2 More often than not, knowing what option to use is 90% of the effort :) I can never remember these string options because autocomplete is of no use here...

Comment: @rm-rf To wit, see edit.  Next to `Automatic`, `None` is the most obvious setting for just about any option.

Comment: I thought the ability to have that context menu was what made your method unique, now it's gone, hehe. And you don't mention that your method is the only one (with mines) that prevent "only" rotation, which sets it apart from Deploy, Overlay, Rasterize. Your method avoiding the context menu still has the advantage over my event handler one of being immune to hotkey tweaking :)

Comment: @Rojo It's a rare day when there's only one way to do something in *Mathematica*. :)

Answer (score 12):

If rotation is all you want to suppress, but you still want zooming and panning, you could do

```
x = 0;
Slider[Dynamic[x], {-.3, .3}]
thermo[Dynamic@x, "\[Alpha]", 20]~Show~{
     ViewVertical -> Dynamic[{0, 0, 1}, Null &], 
     ViewPoint -> Dynamic[{0, -1, 0}, Null &]
  }
```

One could try to turn this into functions. I am not sure how well these work. `AbsoluteOptions` is know to be buggy.

```
dont[ops__][gr_] := 
 Show[gr, Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[
    gr, {ops}] /. (op : Alternatives[ops] -> Dynamic[i_, ___] | i_) :> (op -> 
      Dynamic[i, Null &])]

dontRotate[gr_Graphics3D] := dont[ViewPoint, ViewVertical][gr];
dontZoom[gr_Graphics3D] := dont[ViewAngle][gr];
dontPan[gr_Graphics3D] := dont[ViewCenter][gr];
```

Another way to do this if you haven't changed your hotkeys would be

```
EventHandler[thermo[x, "\[Alpha]", 20], "MouseDown" :> Null, 
 PassEventsDown :> Dynamic[
  CurrentValue["ControlKey"] || CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]]]
```

This last also works without the `Dynamic` but I guess the Futz would scold me if I used that form

Comment: Thank you. A good solution. I prefer the one given by Nasser, just since it enables to once define the function and use it after without any additions.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch definately his solution is the standard most practical way to prevent user interaction.

Comment: (+1) Now all you need is a thermometer controller to connect to *Mathematica*!  By the way, there is weakness in using `Dynamic` on view properties:  If you right-click/control-click on the graphic, the popup menu gives several alternatives, some of which overwrite the settings and destroy the `Dynamic` expressions.

Comment: @MichaelE2, true, I had never seen, let alone used, those options. In that regard, your solution is quite unique, in that you can change the view through the menus and it is still unrotable. Nice

Comment: @Michael E2 It seems that while the approach of Rojo based on the dont... functions admits overriding using the right-click dynamic menu, his approach based on the EventHandler is free of that drawback, as well as the Nasser's approach. Am I right, or I missed something?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch You're quite right.  I was hasty in my description and meant only the first method or two.

Answer (score 8):

dont ovelook the simplest approach..

```
Rasterize[Graphics3D.. ]
```

Comment: Thank you, yes. In order not to suppress the Dynamic functionality Rasterize should be wrapped  by Dynamic. Then the smoothness critically depends upon the  RasterSize. I find RasterSize->200 yields a rather good compromise between smooth slider motion and the thermometer view.

Answer (score 6):

Another simple solution is to replace `Show` by `Overlay@List@Show`.

Comment: Jens, you should try to hit 32,768 and [take a picture.](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/987/im-getting-close-to-5000-points-on-mathematica-stack-exchange)

Comment: Did you miss 2^16 ? I guess, then you'll have to wait until 2^17... Anyway, my current score is special too: 32612, read: 3, 2, 6, 12. Each is the product of the previous two!

Comment: Yes, I did miss 2^16.  Nice pattern you recognized; it would be an interesting game to try to find something special about the reputation number you end each day with.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting side-note re: using the `Method->None` approach is that you can still zoom and pan w/ option/shift. Might not be desirable in all cases.